# Loosing component props when using 'as' styled-component prop on an extended styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, styled-components, styling

**I wrote a CallToAction component like so:**

```
const CallToAction = ({ text = "Default text" }) => (
  <S_CallToAction>{text}</S_CallToAction>
)
const S_CallToAction = styled.div`
  // Some styles...
`
export default CallToAction
```

**Then**, when I want to use it in another components and overload it with some more styles, **I'm loosing** my "text" prop, and the previous styles I declared in my "CallToAction" component.
This works well when I remove the "as={'button'}" prop.

**Here is what I did when I wanted to use it in another component, overloading it:**

```
import CallToAction from "components/common/callToAction"
```

...

```
        <S_ProductButton
          as={'button'}
          text={`I want my text to display and my style being inherited`}
        />
```

...

```
const S_ProductButton = styled(CallToAction)`
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      min-width: 300px;
`
```

**Can someone explain me why adding the "as" prop both makes my style overloading and my text prop don't work anymore ?**
Also, how do you deal with this kind of situation ?

**Note**: *I'm new to styled components... I could export the "S_CallToAction" (styles only) and use it in my other components but is it a good solution? That would break the idea of "one component = one style" to me, which is the idea behind styled-components...*

Answer (score 6):

**Ok, I finally found a solution to my issue !**
There's another prop for my use case which is "**forwardedAs**" used like the "as" prop, and this makes my overloaded styled-component work as intended.

**I had to spread all the props via {...props} on my CallToAction component (which is initially a styled.a)**

```
const CallToAction = ({ text = "Text", href, ...props}) => (
  <S_CallToAction href={href ? href : null} {...props}>{text}</S_CallToAction>
)
```

**And then on my extended component, I had to use forwardedAs:**

```
           <S_ProductButton
              forwardedAs={'button'}
              text={`I have my text and my styles inherited`}
            />
```

**Here are details** about the issue I faced, and why styled-components acts like this: **https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1981**

Comment: You help me a lot!! Thanks!!